# I am trying to find solution to toggle between ltr and rtl view in react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, i18next, expo-updates

I am trying to find solution to toggle between ltr and rtl view in react native expo. I have tried this solution:

```
import * as Updates from "expo-updates";

import {
  I18nManager,
} from "react-native";
// i18 is intialised object of i18next

const changeLanguage = (value) => {
    i18n
      .changeLanguage(value)
      .then(() => {
        setLanguage(value);
        if (value === "ar") {
          if (true && Platform.OS !== "web") {
            I18nManager.allowRTL(true);
            I18nManager.forceRTL(true);
            Updates.reloadAsync();
          }
        } else {
          I18nManager.allowRTL(false);
          I18nManager.forceRTL(false);
          Updates.reloadAsync();
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

but `Updates.reloadAsync();` results in an error:

> Error: You cannot use the Updates module in development mode in a production app. To test manual updates, publish your project using `expo publish` and open the published version in this development client.

So rtl to ltr and ltr to rtl not working.

I have also tried expo publish then also ltr to rtl not working. please give me a solution for that. can you provide me alternative solution for reloading app or if anything wrong i am following in my code then please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you can't use `Updates.reloadAsync()` in development; instead, you can use `DevSettings.reload()` to reload the app.